# Oracle SQL: How to check which of records does not exists in given list of employee id using "IN or NOT IN or other" keywords?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, where-clause, notin

I have 200 Employee ID and following query returns the one exist in database.

```
SELECT * FROM WORKDAY_EMPLOYEE_CORE where PERSONID IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

It is difficult to detect those out of 200 not exist.

Is there any way in SQL to check those which not exist in given list?

Comment: Where does this list of id's that you want to check come from? Gordon and GMB have shown you techniques, but I suspect another x-y question.

Comment: @EdStevens: Those are coming in one file. Those are huge numbers. We search them in Database and database returns what exists but i want to see which among that huge list doe snot exist.

Answer (score 1):

You would typically put the list in a table, or in a derived table, then use `not exists`:

```
select p.personid
from (
    select 1 as personid from dual
    union all select 2 from dual
    union all select 3 from dual
    union all select 4 from dual
) p
where not exists (select 1 from workday_employee_core e where e.personid = p.personid)
```

If you are going to do this often, I would be simpler to actually create a table, and feed it with te list of the values you want search for.

```
create table persons (personid int);
insert into persons (personid) values (1);
insert into persons (personid) values (2);
insert into persons (personid) values (3);
insert into persons (personid) values (4);
```

Then:

```
select p.personid
from persons p
where not exists (select 1 from workday_employee_core e where e.personid = p.personid)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` . . . but you have to generate the list:

```
select x.personid
from (select 1 as personid from dual union all
      select 2 as personid from dual union all
      . . .
     ) x
where not exists (select 1
                  from workday_employee_core wec
                  where wec.personid = x.personid
                 );
```